# rake aborts, don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake, sinatra, delayed-job

I'm trying to get going on my first Ruby (v1.9.3p194) project.  I'm hosting on Heroku, and using Sinatra along with ActiveRecord.  I'm trying to integrate delayed_job into my project, and running into trouble getting rake to recognize jobs:work.  (Yes, I know delayed_job typically works with rails, but as I understand it can work without it.)

So far, I've installed the delayed_job (3.0.3) and delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2) gems using my gemfile/bundler.  Because I don't have rails, I created my own migration file from the delayed_job readme, and migrated it.  I don't think any of this should be causing my issue.

From all the docs I've seen, installing the gems should do the trick. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling them, to no avail.  I'm not sure what else to try - perhaps there's something I need to explicitly include in my rakefile, but I haven't seen any docs that indicate that.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the contents of your `Rakefile`. With sinatra you don't get all the free magical rake task hookups that rails gets. Also try `rake -T` - it will list the available tasks that rake knows about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I have an actual answer for you.

I made a simple project to get `jobs:work` to show up with `rake -T`:

**Gemfile**

```
source :rubygems

gem 'delayed_job'
```

**Rakefile**

```
require 'rake'
require 'bundler'
require Bundler.load.gems.find{|i| i.name == 'delayed_job'}.gem_dir + "/lib/delayed/tasks"
```

*run:* `$ bundle install`

**Result:**

```
$ rake -T
rake jobs:clear  # Clear the delayed_job queue.
rake jobs:work   # Start a delayed_job worker.
```

Comment: My Rakefile contains the following
`require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require './app'`

Comment: I tried your suggestion for the rakefile and now rake does know about jobs:work.  However, now rake seems to get tripped up on the task 'environment'.  Starting to feel like I'm swimming upstream with Sinatra + DJ.  Haven't dug into that issue yet - any more helpful advice?

Comment: You would definitely be well served knowing a bit about how Rails and Sinatra work and where they are different. As for your question about the 'environment' task I don't know what you're asking and would need more details. Open a new SO question for it?